# Getting the Last known location application,Android

Tags: android, google-play-services, location-services

I am trying this simple application(https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/tree/master/BasicLocationSample) which retrieve the last known location of user.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.dell.locationapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

/**
 * Copyright 2014 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */


import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;

/**
 * Location sample.
 *
 * Demonstrates use of the Location API to retrieve the last known location for a device.
 * This sample uses Google Play services (GoogleApiClient) but does not need to authenticate a user.
 * See https://github.com/googlesamples/android-google-accounts/tree/master/QuickStart if you are
 * also using APIs that need authentication.
 */
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
        ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener {

    protected static final String TAG = "basic-location-sample";

    /**
     * Provides the entry point to Google Play services.
     */
    protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    /**
     * Represents a geographical location.
     */
    protected Location mLastLocation;

    protected TextView mLatitudeText;
    protected TextView mLongitudeText;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mLatitudeText = (TextView) findViewById((R.id.latitude_text));
        mLongitudeText = (TextView) findViewById((R.id.longitude_text));

        buildGoogleApiClient();
    Log.d("hh","gg");
    }

    /**
     * Builds a GoogleApiClient. Uses the addApi() method to request the LocationServices API.
     */
    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Runs when a GoogleApiClient object successfully connects.
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        // Provides a simple way of getting a device's location and is well suited for
        // applications that do not require a fine-grained location and that do not need location
        // updates. Gets the best and most recent location currently available, which may be null
        // in rare cases when a location is not available.
        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        if (mLastLocation != null) {
            mLatitudeText.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude()));
            mLongitudeText.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude()));
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.no_location_detected, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        // Refer to the javadoc for ConnectionResult to see what error codes might be returned in
        // onConnectionFailed.
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection failed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = " + result.getErrorCode());
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
        // The connection to Google Play services was lost for some reason. We call connect() to
        // attempt to re-establish the connection.
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection suspended");
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.dell.locationapplication"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.dell.locationapplication.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

build.gradle ( In my Android Studio Project)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.dell.locationapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0'
}
```

I am trying to run it on XOLO Q700, Android Version 4.2.1( API 17 ) and Google Play Services version on my device is 7.0.99.

The application is intended to display the latitude and longitude of user last known location but it's not displaying anything on my device.

I am new to Android.Kindly help me on how to solve this issue.

Comment: Have you inserted your own keys you obtained from the google-console.

Comment: Also are you sure location settings is not OFF in the phone

Comment: Location settings are ON, though I didn't inserted any keys.Can you tell me how to do it?

Comment: Sorry. My Bad. You are not using maps, so you wont need the key!

Comment: Is the toast of no location detected appearing as seen in the code, or nothing is happening at all. Sometimes it does take time to get location co-ordinates.

Comment: Nothing is happening at all and I already waited for sometime .

Comment: What is the location settings type? High accuracy, battery or device only? My device gives a lot of delay on battery saving.

Comment: Hello, did you ever solve this? I am trying to implement the same example, and nothing is happening, no onConnectionFailedTrigger, no error message.

Comment: Never mind, the 'tutorial' I was following (on developer.android.com) forgot to include the call to GoogleApiClient.connect()  I got it working thanks to  your code.

Answer (score -1):

I have tested this example and its working file..!! in my `lenevo a6000 (4.4.4)`
try with other devices

Comment: I tried it on Samsung galaxy tab 2 but it is not working.It seems there is some problem with the code.